# Get the time of published post in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, timestamp

I have a blog in my site. In blog listing, I want to show date and time. I get the published post date with `the_time()`. But the getting time is a tricky part.

I don't want to show posted time e.g. `1:30 PM`

I want to show the time duration of a post ... I mean like this

`53 minutes ago`
or
`4 hours ago`
or 
`2 days ago`
or
`5 months ago`
or
`1 year ago`

I first try this code `get_post_time('U', $post->ID)` or `get_post_time('U', true)` but it gives me the time stamp, Like this `1486128075`

And also try this `get_the_time()` but it gives me `1:00 PM`

Hope you understand my question

Comment: Why don't you calculate it yourself?

Comment: Try [this](https://pastebin.com/n586U9Nm) and use `get_the_time()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in your functions.php

```
function ash_relative_time() { 
$post_date = get_the_time('U');
$delta = time() - $post_date;
if ( $delta < 60 ) {
    echo 'Just Now';
}
elseif ($delta > 60 && $delta < 120){
    echo '1 minute ago';
}
elseif ($delta > 120 && $delta < (60*60)){
    echo strval(round(($delta/60),0)), ' minutes ago';
}
elseif ($delta > (60*60) && $delta < (120*60)){
    echo 'About an hour ago';
}
elseif ($delta > (120*60) && $delta < (24*60*60)){
    echo strval(round(($delta/3600),0)), ' hours ago';
}
else {
    echo the_time('j\<\s\u\p\>S\<\/\s\u\p\> M y g:i a');
}}
```

and then use `echo ash_relative_time();` to  print it.